# RecyclerView multiple headers

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` containing a list of objects of type `Lift`.

The class `Lift` has a function called `date2PrettyString` which returns a `DateTime`in `dd MMM. yyyy` format.

I want to display all `Lift` objects but create a header every time a lift with another date is displayed.

For example, assume I have 5 objects of type `Lift` with the following output of `date2PrettyString`

- ob1: 03 Dec. 2018
- ob2: 03 Dec. 2018
- ob3: 01 Dec. 2018
- ob4: 05 Aug. 2018
- ob5: 05 Aug. 2018

The resulting list I want is the following:

- 03 Dec. 2018
- ob1.getName();
- ob2.getName();
- 01 Dec. 2018
- ob3.getName();
- 05 Aug. 2018
- ob4.getName();
- ob5.getName();

The list that comes into the adapter is always sorted descending based on the date (just like in the example).

I have a layout created for the `TextView` which displays the date and another one for the `TextView` displaying the name.

Some of my adapter code is the following

```
    public ExerciseLiftsRecyclerAdapter(RealmResults<Lift> itemList, Context context, View.OnClickListener listener, Fragment fragment) {
        this.mItemsList = itemList;
        this.mFragment = fragment;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.adapter_lift_text, parent, false);
            view.setOnClickListener(mListener);
            viewHolder = new LiftTextHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.adapter_lift_date, parent, false);
            view.setOnClickListener(mListener);
            viewHolder = new DateTextHolder(view);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (position == 1)
            return false;

        // not sure what to put here  for positions > 1
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        this.mCurrentLift = mItemsList.get(position - (int) mItemsList.stream().limit(position).map(Lift::date2PrettyString).count()); // not sure if that's right

        if (holder instanceof LiftTextHolder) {
            LiftTextHolder itemViewHolder = (LiftTextHolder) holder;
            //do stuff
        } else if (holder instanceof DateTextHolder) {
            DateTextHolder mHolder = (DateTextHolder) holder;
            //do stuff
        }
    }

    private Lift getClickedLift() {
        return mCurrentLift;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemsList.size() + (int) mItemsList.stream().map(Lift::date2PrettyString).distinct().count();
    }
```

I'm pretty lost on how to return the appropriate value inside the `getItemViewType` function and if what I've done in the `onBindViewHolder` one is good.

Best solution that comes to mind is for each position to calculate using streams how many distinct dates are (similar to what I did inside the `OnBindViewHolder`. But I'm not sure if it's a good idea because I don't know what to compare it to in the `getItemViewType` function because it's not known whether the users scrolls up or down.

Comment: I've prepared them in a sense that the objects are already in a descending order by date